# Send Facebook notification to user who registered on my site via facebook connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, notifications

Let me start by saying facebook's developer documentation sucks. Bad.

I'm using the facebooker plugin in rails to let users sign up through facebook connect. Now when certain things occur I want to send notifications to certain users through facebook. I heard some say that notifications must go from one user to another, but I've seen evidence otherwise. I signed up at the site http://www.meetingwave.com/ through fb connect, and now they send me (annoyingly) daily notifications of new things on their site. Also, using the comments widget on my own site [www.tmatthew.net](http://www.meetingwave.com/), when an anonymous user leaves a comment I get notified of that as well.

So uh, how do you do that? I've been googling all week long and can't seem to find anything. It seems like I should be able to send a notification from my app to one of it's users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The api call you are looking for is called [Notifications.send](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Notifications.send).  The only thing is that they will be disabling it very soon so there is probably no point in implementing it into your application.